# heroku-22 stack discord.py bot doesn't play music

Tags: python, heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm making music bot with discord.py and using heroku. bot is playing music my localhost but heroku host is not playing music.

I found what cause a bug.
It working nicely in heroku-20, but not working in heroku-22 stack.

How can I use heroku-22 stack without error?
What can I do?

I'm sorry my english is bad.

my code:

```
import youtube_dl
import discord
from discord import app_commands,Interaction
import asyncio
import os

class MyClient(discord.Client):
  async def on_ready(self):
    await self.wait_until_ready()
    await tree.sync()
    print(f"login at {self.user}")
        
intents= discord.Intents.all()
client = MyClient(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''
ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
}
ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)
class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=True):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))
        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data=data['entries'][0]
        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)
queue={}
@tree.command(name="play", description="play music")
async def playmusic(interaction:Interaction,url_title:str,playfirst:bool=False):
  await interaction.response.send_message("I'm looking for music!!")
  guild=str(interaction.guild.id)
  try:
    queue[guild]
  except KeyError:
    queue[guild]=[]
  if interaction.user.voice is None:
    await interaction.edit_original_response(content="you must join any voice channel")
  else:
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=interaction.guild)
    if voice_client == None:
      await interaction.user.voice.channel.connect()
      voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=interaction.guild)
    player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url_title, loop=None)
    if playfirst and len(queue[guild])>1:
      queue[guild].insert(1,player)
    else:
      queue[guild].append(player)
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
      voice_client.play(player,after=None)
      await interaction.edit_original_response(content=f"{player.title} playing!!")
    else:
      await interaction.edit_original_response(content=f"{player.title} enqueued!")
    await asyncio.sleep(7)
    await interaction.delete_original_response()

client.run(token)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.